# jQuery ImageDropdown with Egg plugin not working on IE7 or IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7, skinning

I am using the [Egg ImageDropdown plugin](http://egg.liam-galvin.co.uk/?p=demo_imagedropdown) to have a dropdown of images. It works very well on FF, Chrome and IE9, however on IE7 and IE8 the native dropdown sits on top of the skinned dropdown and makes neither of them clickable.

I have the following jQuery and markup installed, as per the documentation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.egg_imagedropdown').EggImageDropdown();      
});
        <select name="banners" id="banners" class="egg_imagedropdown">              
            <option value='1'>/downloads/Image/1.jpg</option>   
            <option value='2'>/downloads/Image/2.jpg</option>   
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for EggImageDropdown to fail to work on IE7 and IE8 was that I had the page calling Egg within an `iframe` which didn't have the following DOCTYPE declaration. It must be set as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```